# Sync Problem ( No Apps are installed to open this type of link (grvopen)

Tags: sync

I tried to sync my document but every time .. this message is shown to me[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it ..
Only i didn't install the skyDrive Pro 2013 
when you setup Office 2013 .. don't forget to install or select the sky drive pro.. if you did >> only return to office install and add feature ( skyDrive pro )